# Split array (indexed list) into two rows if on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my ionic project I'm trying to integrate a kind of indexed list but then horizontal. The list is good as it is now, but I want to support small screen devices too, thus wanting to split the list in two rows as the screen is smaller than let's say 700px.

Desired output: http://tinypic.com/r/16gu3r/8 
This is what i have so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/20T3fpKfAq7P0QQTddEo

```js
$scope.alphabet = {
A: {
  name: "A",
  amount: 0
},
B: {
  name: "B",
  amount: 0
},
C: {
  name: "C",
  amount: 0
},
D: {
  name: "D",
  amount: 0
},
E: {
  name: "E",
  amount: 0
},
F: {
  name: "F",
  amount: 0
},
G: {
  name: "G",
  amount: 0
},
H: {
  name: "H",
  amount: 0
},
I: {
  name: "I",
  amount: 0
},
J: {
  name: "J",
  amount: 0
},
K: {
  name: "K",
  amount: 0
},
L: {
  name: "L",
  amount: 0
},
M: {
  name: "M",
  amount: 0
},
N: {
  name: "N",
  amount: 0
},
O: {
  name: "O",
  amount: 0
},
P: {
  name: "P",
  amount: 0
},
Q: {
  name: "Q",
  amount: 0
},
R: {
  name: "R",
  amount: 0
},
S: {
  name: "S",
  amount: 0
},
T: {
  name: "T",
  amount: 0
},
U: {
  name: "U",
  amount: 0
},
V: {
  name: "V",
  amount: 0
},
W: {
  name: "W",
  amount: 0
},
X: {
  name: "X",
  amount: 0
},
Y: {
  name: "Y",
  amount: 0
},
Z: {
  name: "Z",
  amount: 0
}
};
```

```css
.button-alphabet {
  background: transparent;
  color: #777;
  width: 3.8%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: inline;
}
.button-alphabet[disabled] {
  border: none;
}
.button-alphabet:nth-of-type(13):after {
  content: "\A";
 white-space: pre;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="row center">
  <button ng-repeat="letter in alphabet" class="button-alphabet">{{letter.name}}</button>
</div>
```

I've tried setting the buttons on inline and using the :after selector to force a line break after the 13th element, but no luck so far.

With Javascript this is the desired result, but with this I'm having an index issue. When I select the upper 'B', the letter 'O' beneath it, is selected also. They share the same index in the array

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ima2dVxEsXVNPfljEsAF

Tried searching the SO topics, but couldn't come up with a good solution,. Would it be able to programmatically split the array into two rows? Could i achieve this with CSS alone? Or should I stick with Javscript? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do this using `ng-repeat-start` and then with `ng-repeat-end`  add a block element as separator

HTML

```
<button ng-repeat-start="letter in alphabet" ...>{{letter.name}}</button>
<div ng-repeat-end ng-if="$index==12" class="separator"></div>
```

CSS

```
 .separator{
    display:none;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width:700px){
    .separator{          
      display:block;
    }
  }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/MCtxqSfufChtVRlQXntI?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

First of all there was a syntax error on using the `ng-class`.

This is the correct syntax:

```
ng-class="{ current : $index == 13 }"
```

I've update the code. I don't know if visually this is the desired result, but i've applied the ng-class for the 13th element and defined the css style used on your example.

[Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/FgTVezSL7U6ODRXwjGYM?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, i'll update my code to have the correct syntax. However this is not the effect i was looking for. I'm trying to break the buttons so that the buttons (now all in 1 row) are spread out over 2 rows.

Comment: And from which element do you want to break? You mentioned the 13th element.

Comment: That is true, it splits the array evenly then. But I want to break, and continue with the flow on the same line like so:  http://tinypic.com/r/16gu3r/8. Setting a block element on $index: 13 is not what i'm after.